# Find the series expansion for $\int_0^x e^{-t^2}dt$ for $x\in \mathbb R$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Find the series expansion for $$\int_0^x e^{-t^2}dt \text{ for } x\in \mathbb R$$

$\textbf{The added question:}$

Is it possible to reverse? If so, if we are given a series expansion what is the method to get back the integral or the respective funtion?

Comment: Substitute $-t^2$ for $x$ in  the series for $e^x$. Then integrate term by term.

Comment: Note that both of the users that gave answers integrated the series for $e^{-t^2}$ term-by-term. This was not necessary as you could find a Taylor series in the usual way and making use of the fundamental theorem of calculus. However in many instances you *do not* want to do it this way because it will make your expressions much more complicated. The safe bet is to do it the way both users below approached it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

\begin{aligned}
\int_0^{x} e^{-t^2} dt & = \int_0^x \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-t^2)^n}{n!}dt = \\
& = \left\{\text{Integrate each term separately}\right\} = \\
& =\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{n!}\int_0^x t^{2n}dt = \\
& = \sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{n!}\left[\frac{t^{2n+1}}{2n+1}\right]^{t=x}_{t=0} = \\
& = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^nx^{2n+1}}{n!(2n+1)}
\end{aligned}

Answer (score 3):

$$e^{-t^2} =1+ \frac{-t^2}{1!} +\frac{(-t^2)^2}{2!}+\ldots$$

If we integrate with respect to $t$ between the upper limit ($x$) & lower limit ($0$) we will get $x-x^3/(3*1!)+x^5/(5*2!)+\ldots$.
The nth term will be $(-1)^{n-1} \frac{x^{2n-1}}{(2n-1)(n-1)!}$
   Here $n=1,2,3,\ldots$